# Land cover, land-cover, or landcover?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

In literature, I often see *landcover*, *land cover*, and even *land-cover*. *Land cover* seems slightly more prevalent than the others. Which is correct?

Land cover is the material covering the Earth's surface: grass, trees, concrete, *etc.* Here's the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_cover).

I typically use it in the context of:

> The land cover dataset…
>
> 90% of land cover classes were…

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules that determine how compounds, especially less common ones, are written (open, hyphenated, closed) in English. There are barely even soft and slow ones. Write it however you think looks best—as long as you're consistent. As you say, open compounds are most common; but _land(-)cover_ is short and simple enough to work just fine any which way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Land cover (written as an open compound) does appear more frequently. See the link below for the frequency of each form. If the compound is not permanent i.e. common enough that it has been accepted in a particular form and appears in dictionaries, I suggest you follow convention.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=landcover%2Cland+cover%2Cland-cover&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clandcover%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cland%20cover%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cland%20-%20cover%3B%2Cc0

This link below contains useful information regarding compounds. In particular, see the sections titled "Compounds in the Dictionary" and "The Compound-styling Conundrum."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq/compound.htm

Answer (score 1):

[*A long time ago in a com­ment far, far away*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH-jLrirmM8), Janus Bahs Jac­quet wrote:

> There are no hard and fast rules that de­ter­mine how com­pounds, 
>   es­pe­cially less com­mon ones, are writ­ten (open,
>   hy­phen­ated, closed) in English. There are barely even soft and
>   slow ones. Write it how­ever you think looks best—as long as you’re
>   con­sis­tent. As you say, open com­pounds are most com­mon; but
>   *land(-)cover* is short and sim­ple enough to work just fine any
>   which way.